# First time using Promise.all and have a few problems getting JSON to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have 2 files, JavaScript and HTML. I am trying to get data from 3 urls and display the title in my HTML. I believe I have the most part but I can't get the data to show.

I am trying to print all title objects in my HTML page.

I get this error in my console

> ```
> example.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined
>     at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (example.js:24)
>     at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
>     at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
> ```

My HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var showData = $('#show-data');

      $.getJSON('data.json ', function(data) {

        var items = data.map(function(item) {
          return item.title;
        });

        if (items.length) {
          var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
          var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
          showData.append(list);
        }
      });


    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" id="get-data">get data</a>
  <div id="show-data"></div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var first = 'https://1';
  var second = 'https://2';
  var third = 'https://3';

  Promise.all([
    $.getJSON(first),
    $.getJSON(second),
    $.getJSON(third)
  ]).then(function(data) {

    $('#get-data').click(function() {
      var showData = $('#show-data');
      $.getJSON(first, function(data) {
        showData.empty();
        var items = data.map(function(elem) {
          return $("<li />", {
            text: elem.title
          });
        });
      })

      var list = $('<ul />').append(items);
      showData.append(list);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: items is defined inside inner getJSON callback which won't get called until a click occurs. Adding click listener inside `then()` doesn't really make much sense either. Going to need explanation of what exactly you are trying to do here

Comment: Ok is there a easy way to fix my code ?

Comment: why you have this `$('#get-data').click(function() {` inside the then

Comment: Also, why are you calling ` $.getJSON(first)` again?

Comment: thanks fixing this now

Comment: Think, after the promises are fulfilled, what would like to happen?

Comment: run the promises, so remove the first, as we are calling the promise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142647/discussion-between-funcoding-and-beep).

Comment: ive got to go but ill be back soon, thanks for your help @funcoding

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the nested click which doesn't make a lot of sense, you probably want something more like:

```
var showData = $('#show-data'),
  urls = ['data.json', 'data2.json', 'data3.json'],
  // map url array to array of ajax promises
  requests = urls.map((url) => $.getJSON(url));

Promise.all(requests).then(processData);

function processData(data) {
  console.log(data) // array of arrays
  showData.empty();
 // flatten array of arrays to array of jQ objects
  var items = data.reduce(function(a, c) {
    var elems = c.map(function(elem) {
      return $("<li />", {
        text: elem.title
      });
    })
    return a.concat(elems)
  }, []);

  var list = $('<ul />').append(items);
  showData.append(list);
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/aG3wXEZxFBNTd5IgXmGY?p=preview)**</kbd>